# How to set a range in do/while range in c?

Tags: c, do-while

I want the user to input a height in range 2-8 inclusive if any other number is entered it should re-prompt user ... i have tried

```
int main(void)
{
    int height;
    do{
        height = get_int("Enter The Height: ");
    }
    while (height<=1 && height<=9);
    return height;
}
```

the program runs with no errors but even if I input 9 it does not re-prompt me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. It should be `while (!(2 <= height && height <= 8))`.

For example when `height == 9` in your original logic it ends up being `false && true`, which is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to ask again as long as the height is outside of the desired range. So you want to ask again as long as the height is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum.

```
do {
   ...
} while (height < 2 || height > 8);
```

You were using `&&` where you should have be using `||`, and `<=` where you should have been using `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

> well you need the "OR" operator instead of "AND", to get in the loop you need one of the conditions should be different from the other ie., "< >".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
int i, j, k, h;
int a, b;

do
{
    printf("Enter the heights: ");
    scanf("%d", &h);
} while (h < 0 || h > 8);

for (i = 0; i <= h; i++)
{
    for (k = h; k >= i; k--)
    {
        printf(" . ");
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {

        printf(" # ");
    }

    for (a = 0; a < 2; a++)
    {
        printf(" . ");
    }

    for (b = 0; b <= i; b++)
    {
        printf(" # ");
    }

    printf("\n");
}
}
```